# This code hits a roadblock on Android, any idea why?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

The method below runs great on ios Iphone 5, Mac, PC, and web but has major slowdown on Android. This is in unity 5 c#.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using OpenCVForUnity;

public class MouthDetect : MonoBehaviour
{

    private WebCamTexture _webCamTexture;
    private Color32[] _colors;
    public bool isFrontFacing = true;
    public int webCamTextureWidth = 640;
    public int webCamTextureHeight = 480;
    public int webCamTextureFPS = 10;
    private string _firstCam; // For debuging with no front facing camera.
    private Mat _rgbaMat;
    private Mat _grayMat;
    private Mat _mouthMATGray;
    private Mat _mouthMATRGBA;
    private Texture2D _texture;
    private CascadeClassifier _cascadeFace;
    private CascadeClassifier _cascadeMouth;
    private MatOfRect _faces;
    private MatOfRect _mouths;
    private bool _initDone = false;
    private OpenCVForUnity.Rect _mouthROI = new OpenCVForUnity.Rect();

    // Chew detection
    private UnityEngine.Rect _rectMouth;
    private int _mouthWidth;  // 
    private int _mouthHeight;
    private double _totalBright = new double();  // Total brightness inside the mouth
    private double _lastBright = 0; // The last extreme value of open or closed.
    private Texture2D _textMouth;
    private bool _mouthIsOpenBoolean = false;  // Is the mouth open? boolean
    public double mouthChangeDiff = 0.2;  // The difference between brightness before a mout is opened or closed.  Smaller detects more chews but can be prone to false chews.
    public int mouthDetectPixelCount = 10;  // How many pixels should we use for detection?
    private bool _mouthFound = false;
    private bool _faceFound = false;

    // Debug logic
    private GameObject _previewToggle;
    private GameObject _previewScreen;
    private Image _previewImage;
    private FaceDetPreview _previewScript;
    private bool _debugPreviewOn = false;
    private Sprite _webCamSprite;
    private string _cameraInf = "";
    private GameObject _cameraList;
    private DebugCameras _cameraListScript;
    private string _selectedCamera = "";

    // Create an array of OpenCV rectangles from the array of faces. Andy
    OpenCVForUnity.Rect[] rects;
    // Create an array of OpenCV rectangles from the array of mouths.
    OpenCVForUnity.Rect[] rectsM;

    // Detection logic
    public int logicSolution = 1; // Which solution are we using?  0 = brightness, 1 = find/lose mouth.
    private bool _capturingFace = false;

    public bool mouthIsOpenBoolean {
        get { return _mouthIsOpenBoolean; }
        set { 
            // Make sure we've changed.
            if (_mouthIsOpenBoolean==value) 
                return;

            _mouthIsOpenBoolean = value; 

            // Add a chew if we've changed to false
            if (value == false) {
                GameObject chewText = GameObject.Find ("Chews");
                Chewing chewing = chewText.GetComponent<Chewing>();
                chewing.AddChew();
            }
        }
    }


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        // Get the debug preview toggle and image
        _previewToggle = GameObject.Find ("FacePreviewToggle");
        _previewScript = _previewToggle.GetComponent<FaceDetPreview> ();
        _previewScreen =  GameObject.Find ("FacePreview");
        _previewImage = _previewScreen.GetComponent<Image> ();
        _cameraList = GameObject.Find ("Cameras");
        if(_cameraList!=null)
            _cameraListScript = _cameraList.GetComponent<DebugCameras>();

        // Setup camera and texture
        StartCoroutine (init ());
    }

    private IEnumerator init ()
    {
        // Have we already initialised?  Restart if we have.
        if (_webCamTexture != null) {
            _webCamTexture.Stop ();
            _initDone = false;

            _rgbaMat.Dispose ();
            _grayMat.Dispose ();
        }

        // Checks how many and which cameras are available on the device
        _cameraInf = "Cameras=" + WebCamTexture.devices.Length.ToString ();
        for (int cameraIndex = 0; cameraIndex < WebCamTexture.devices.Length; cameraIndex++) {
            // Debug information
            AddToDebug( "Camera " + cameraIndex.ToString() + " - " + WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].name + 
                       " - Front:" + WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].isFrontFacing);

            // We want to be using the correct camera, make sure it's front facing
            if (WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].isFrontFacing == isFrontFacing) {
                // Tell us which camera we're using
                Debug.Log (cameraIndex + " name " + WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].name + " isFrontFacing " + WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].isFrontFacing);
                Debug.Log("Here");

                // Set the camera texture
                _webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture (WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].name, webCamTextureWidth, webCamTextureHeight);
                break;
            }
            else {

                // We only want the first one
                if (_firstCam=="") {
                    _firstCam=WebCamTexture.devices [cameraIndex].name;

                }
            }
        }

        // Did we find a camera?
        if (_webCamTexture == null) {
            // If we're in unity this is ok...
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
            // Just create a new camera
            _webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture (_firstCam, webCamTextureWidth, webCamTextureHeight);
            #endif

            // ****** We need a stop here!!!!!! ***************************************************************************
            // TODO: The device has no forward facing camera
            // We can't chew without a front facing camera!!!
        }

        // Debug...
        AddToDebug ("Selected Camera: " + _webCamTexture.deviceName);
        Debug.Log(_webCamTexture.deviceName);

        // How many fps do we want??  We need to control the performance.  Although, this request is usually ignored! :/
        _webCamTexture.requestedFPS = webCamTextureFPS;

        // Start the camera
        _webCamTexture.Play ();

        while (true) {
            //If you want to use webcamTexture.width and webcamTexture.height on iOS, you have to wait until webcamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame == 1, otherwise these two values will be equal to 16. (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webcamtexture-and-error-0x0502.123922/)
            if (_webCamTexture.width > 16 && _webCamTexture.height > 16) {
                // Create a new colour and matrices
                _colors = new Color32[_webCamTexture.width * _webCamTexture.height];
                _rgbaMat = new Mat (_webCamTexture.height, _webCamTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
                _grayMat = new Mat (_webCamTexture.height, _webCamTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                _mouthMATRGBA = new Mat (_webCamTexture.height, _webCamTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
                _mouthMATGray = new Mat (_webCamTexture.height, _webCamTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                _texture = new Texture2D (_webCamTexture.width, _webCamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
                _textMouth = new Texture2D (_webCamTexture.width, _webCamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

                // Set the rotation
                //              gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);

                // For Android and iPhone the rotation needs to change to correct the z axis
                /*              #if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE) && !UNITY_EDITOR
                    gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, -90);
                #endif
*/
                // I'm not sure why this was removed in the sample, I'll leave it out until I figure out what it's ueseful for,  
                // It looks like the developer is trying to dynamically correct rotated webcams.
                //  gameObject.transform.rotation = gameObject.transform.rotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis (_webCamTexture.videoRotationAngle, Vector3.back);

                // It looks like we were dynamically fixing scale????  Why is the dev removing this???  I may re-introduce it.
                /*  bool videoVerticallyMirrored = _webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored;
                    float scaleX = 1;
                    float scaleY = videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1.0f : 1.0f;
                    if (_webCamTexture.videoRotationAngle == 270)
                        scaleY = -1.0f;
                    gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (scaleX * gameObject.transform.localScale.x, scaleY * gameObject.transform.localScale.y, 1);
                */

                // Create the new classifiers - TODO we have some work to do with this path to make it work with Android and iPhone...
                _cascadeFace = new CascadeClassifier (Utils.getFilePath ("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")); 
                _cascadeMouth = new CascadeClassifier (Utils.getFilePath ("haarcascade_mouth.xml"));  


                // Create a matrix of faces (we'll load it at some point???....)
                _faces = new MatOfRect ();
                _mouths = new MatOfRect ();

                // Set the camera ortho size, don't this this will work with the frog camera.
                Camera.main.orthographicSize = _webCamTexture.width / 2;

                // We're initilised
                _initDone = true;

                break;
            } 
            else {
                // Come back and try again, we're not ready yet.
                yield return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        // Make sure we've initialised.
        if ((_initDone) && (!_capturingFace)) {
            StartCoroutine ("CaptureFace");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator CaptureFace() {
        _capturingFace = true;

        // Make sure that the texture has been correctly formated, if not we'll have to come back later.
        if (_webCamTexture.width > 16 && _webCamTexture.height > 16) {

            // Pass the web cam texture to a OpenCV matrix
            Utils.webCamTextureToMat (_webCamTexture, _rgbaMat, _colors);

            // iPhones buggering about with mirroring again...
            #if UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR
            // Flip if neccessary
            if (_webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored){
                if(isFrontFacing){
                    Core.flip (_rgbaMat, _rgbaMat, 1);
                }else{
                    Core.flip (_rgbaMat, _rgbaMat, 0);
                }
            }else{
                if(isFrontFacing){
                    Core.flip (_rgbaMat, _rgbaMat, -1);
                }
            }
            #endif

            // Convert the rgb web texture matrix to gray
            Imgproc.cvtColor (_rgbaMat, _grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

            // Adjust the contrast - this can impact performance, try without for faster performance
            Imgproc.equalizeHist (_grayMat, _grayMat);

            // Set the cascade to detect different sized targets
            if (_cascadeFace != null)
                _cascadeFace.detectMultiScale (_grayMat, _faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                                               new Size (_webCamTexture.width * 0.15, _webCamTexture.width * 0.15), new Size ());

            // Create an array of OpenCV rectangles from the array of faces.
            rects = _faces.toArray ();

            // Find a mouth in each face each face.
            _faceFound = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < rects.Length; i++) {

                // We found a face
                _faceFound = true;

                // For debugging, show us where the face is.
                Core.rectangle (
                    _rgbaMat, 
                    new Point (rects [i].x ,rects [i].y), 
                    new Point (rects [i].x + rects [i].width, rects [i].y + rects [i].height), 
                    new Scalar (0, 255, 0, 255), 
                    2);

                // Create a rectangle around the region of the face we're interested in
                // Keep it inside the face box, otherwise we get errors when we're at the edge of the screen
                /*              OpenCVForUnity.Rect _mouthROI = new OpenCVForUnity.Rect(
                    (int)rects [i].x,
                    (int)rects [i].y + (rects [i].height / 2),
                    (int)rects [i].width,
                    (int)(rects [i].height- (rects [i].height / 2)));
*/              OpenCVForUnity.Rect _mouthROI = new OpenCVForUnity.Rect(            // IMPROVED SENSITIVITY!!!!
                                                                             (int)rects [i].x,
                                                                             (int)rects [i].y + ((rects [i].height / 3) * 2),
                                                                             (int)rects [i].width,
                                                                             (int)(rects [i].height - ((rects [i].height / 3) * 2)));

                // Create a new matrix using the ROI 
                _mouthMATGray = _grayMat.submat(_mouthROI);
                _mouthMATRGBA = _rgbaMat.submat(_mouthROI);

                // Detect the mouth (we're only going to use the first mouth captured
                // Set the cascade to detect different sized targets
                if (_cascadeMouth != null)
                    _cascadeMouth.detectMultiScale (_mouthMATGray, _mouths, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                                                    new Size (_webCamTexture.width * 0.04, _webCamTexture.width * 0.04), new Size ());
                // Create an array of OpenCV rectangles from the array of mouths.
                rectsM = _mouths.toArray ();

                // Put a rectangle around the first mouth on each face
                _mouthFound = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < rectsM.Length; j++) {
                    // Set the mouth box and make sure that the x and y are correct (remember, these co-ords are inside the ROI)
                    _rectMouth = new UnityEngine.Rect(
                        rectsM[j].x + _mouthROI.x,
                        _webCamTexture.height - _mouthROI.y - rectsM[j].y - rectsM[j].height,
                        rectsM[j].width,
                        rectsM[j].height
                        );

                    // We've found a mouth! 
                    _mouthFound = true;

                    Core.rectangle (
                        _rgbaMat, 
                        new Point (rectsM [j].x + _mouthROI.x,rectsM [j].y + _mouthROI.y), 
                        new Point (rectsM [j].x + rectsM [j].width + _mouthROI.x, rectsM [j].y + rectsM [j].height + _mouthROI.y), 
                        new Scalar (0, 0, 255, 255), 
                        2);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Add the output to the asssigned texture!
            Utils.matToTexture2D (_rgbaMat, _texture, _colors);

            // Are we debugging?
            _debugPreviewOn = _previewScript.isToggled;
            if (_debugPreviewOn) {
                _webCamSprite = Sprite.Create(
                    _texture, 
                    new UnityEngine.Rect(
                    0,
                    0,
                    _texture.width,
                    _texture.height), 
                    new Vector2(0,0));
                _previewImage.sprite = _webCamSprite;
            }

            //Debug.Log("Face:" + _faceFound.ToString() + " Mouth:" + _mouthFound.ToString());



            // Which version are we using??  The fact that we have a mouth with satisfy the "find/lose mouth" method
            if (logicSolution==1) {
                // We're setting the oposite of mouth found (ie, if we've found the mouth it's closed
                mouthIsOpenBoolean = !_mouthFound;
            }

            // Only continue for solution 0 and we have a mouth.
            if ((logicSolution==0) && (_mouthFound==true)) {
                Debug.Log("We shouldn't see this");

                // How high and wide are the mouth
                _mouthWidth = (int)_rectMouth.width;
                _mouthHeight = (int)_rectMouth.height;

                // Create the mouth texture
                Color[] pixels = _texture.GetPixels(
                    (int)_rectMouth.x,
                    (int)_rectMouth.y,
                    (int)_rectMouth.width,
                    (int)_rectMouth.height);
                _textMouth.Resize(_mouthWidth, _mouthHeight);
                _textMouth.Apply();
                _textMouth.SetPixels(pixels);
                _textMouth.Apply();

                // Work out detection pixels
                int mouthCentre = _mouthWidth / 2;
                _totalBright = 0;
                int mouthGap = _mouthHeight / mouthDetectPixelCount;
                UnityEngine.Rect rectShapePreview = 
                    new UnityEngine.Rect((float)mouthCentre - 1, (float)mouthGap,3, (float)mouthGap*(float)mouthDetectPixelCount);

                // Work out the gap between the pixels
                for (int i = 1; i <= mouthDetectPixelCount; i++)
                {
                    // Work out the total brightness
                    int pixelY = mouthGap * i;
                    _totalBright += Brightness(_textMouth.GetPixel(mouthCentre, pixelY));
                }

                // Have we opened or closed.
                //
                // Rules will be (for boolean):
                //  1. The initial change will be 2 tenths in eather direction (double mouthChangeDiff) to change open or closed.  
                //      Smaller = Open, Bigger = Closed.
                //  2. Record the current number into _lastBright (double) and start closed (bool - false) in mouthIsOpenBoolean
                //  3. If the number gets bigger keep updating the _lastBright variable to make note of the "close" brightness.
                //  4. If the number gets smaller measure it, if it's more then 2/10s (or what ever the variable is we're now open:
                //      change the bool to true and record the number.
                //      If it's less just leave it, this will help us if we capture the mouth when it's mid open or mid close.
                //  5. If we've moved to closed do stops to to 4 but in the oposite direction
                //
                // Rules will be (for integer)
                //  1. Use boolean logic but the change diff maximimum is 100 (open - oposite to boolean :S) and minimum is 0 (closed);
                //  2. Use the increment to tie the setting to the nearest increment.

                // Record the current number into _lastBright if this is the first capture
                if (_lastBright == 0) {
                    _lastBright = _totalBright;
                } 
                else {
                    //Get the difference
                    double diff = new double();
                    diff = _lastBright - _totalBright;

                    // We need a positive diff too
                    double posDiff = diff;
                    if (posDiff < 0) {posDiff = -posDiff;}

                    // Have we gone more open or more closed?
                    if (((_lastBright > _totalBright) && (mouthIsOpenBoolean)) ||
                        ((_lastBright < _totalBright) && (!mouthIsOpenBoolean))) {

                        // We're going further in the same direction, log the last brighness
                        _lastBright = _totalBright;
                    }
                    else {
                        // We've changed direction.  If it is more than the diff level set???
                        if (posDiff > mouthChangeDiff) {
                            // We've changed direction!
                            if (mouthIsOpenBoolean) {
                                mouthIsOpenBoolean = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                mouthIsOpenBoolean = true;
                            }

                            // Set the new last brightness
                            _lastBright = _totalBright;
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);     // Massive performance boost.
        _capturingFace = false;
        yield return null;
    }

    void OnDisable ()
    {
        // Stop the webcam.
        _webCamTexture.Stop ();
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        float screenScale = Screen.width / 240.0f;
        Matrix4x4 scaledMatrix = Matrix4x4.Scale (new Vector3 (screenScale, screenScale, screenScale));
        GUI.matrix = scaledMatrix;

        // How big is our GUI Box?
        //      UnityEngine.Rect devRect = new UnityEngine.Rect (1, 1, (_texture.width/10)+2, (_texture.height/10)+90);

    }

    // Return the brighness of the colour of a pixel
    private double Brightness(Color c) 
    {
        return Mathf.Sqrt (
            c.r * c.r * .241f + 
            c.g * c.g * .691f + 
            c.b * c.b * .068f);
    }

    public void AddToDebug(string newLine) {

        // Do we need to add a carraige return
        if (_cameraInf != "") 
            _cameraInf += "\n";

        // Add the line and update us
        _cameraInf += newLine;
        if (_cameraListScript!=null)
            _cameraListScript.cameraList = _cameraInf;

    }

}
```

Specifically in the `update()` `Ienumerator` `captureface()` is taking 150ms plus to run according to the profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use CPU-heavy functions, specifically

```
_textMouth.SetPixels(pixels);
_textMouth.Apply();
```

And it's not platform-dependent issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe just my devices for testing then but I assumed my htcM8 was pretty good compared to Iphone5 which runs it quite easily.  Is there nothing that stands out that may struggle with android but not iphone?  Do you have any suggestions for different methods instead of those two?

Comment: I dont really know how to fix this, but I can give you advice how to find out what exactly causes this performance drops. Change your code to something like [this](http://pastebin.com/mz92dLs9). This will allow you to see how much time every function was executed. Comparing results on your HTC M8 and iPhone will help you find out which line of code causes drops. I hope you get the idea.